# How Virtual Textures work?

Tags: textures, optimization

I'm trying to understand how  Virtual Textures work. After coming across this post:

- https://discourse.threejs.org/t/virtual-textures/53353

And more research here:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/svt-how-it-works.html

Are  Virtual Textures essentially a render target with multiple plane meshes (tiles), each having textures applied? And for a given plane mesh, it switches to a high-resolution texture based on the player's position? If so, isn't the Virtual Textures limited by the resolution of the render target?

Comment: Is your question about Unity specifically or game development in general?

Comment: @Kevin game development in general. The general workings of a  Virtual Texture

Comment: I remember reading several articles about how "MegaTextures" worked in Rage that were very accessible, sometime shortly after the game first released. I don't know off the top of my head how similar modern Virtual Texture implementations are to id Tech 5's MegaTexture implementation, but reading about MegaTexture is probably a good start for understanding the concept.

Comment: Virtual texturing *can* involve render targets, but they don't necessarily have to. It's mostly about managing which parts of the texture need to be loaded to the GPU and on what mip mapping level at any given moment. Are you looking for a simple definition or for more practical advise on how to integrate this into your game? If the latter, you might want to be a bit more specific about the problem you are encountering.